# Running a pyspark program on python3 kernel in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I used `pip install pyspark` to install PySpark. I didn't set any path etc.; however, I found that everything was downloaded and copied into `C:/Users/Admin/anaconda3/scripts`. I opened jupyter notebook in a Python3 kernel and I tried to run a SystemML script but it was giving me an error. I realized that I needed to place winutils.exe in `C:/Users/Admin/anaconda3/scripts` as well, so I did that and the script ran as expected.

Now, my program includes GridSearch and when I run it on my personal laptop, it is markedly slower than how it is on a Cloud data platform where I can initiate a kernel with Spark (such as IBM Watson Studio).

So my questions are:

(i) How do I add PySpark to the Python3 kernel? Or is it already working in the background when I `import pyspark`?

(ii) When I run the same code on the same dataset using pandas and scikit-learn, there is not much difference in performance. When is PySpark preferred/beneficial over pandas and scikit-learn?

Another thing is, even though PySpark seems to be working fine and I'm able to import its libraries, when I try to run

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

it throws up and error (on line 2), saying the `list is out of range`. I googled a bit and found an advice that said that I had to explicitly set `SPARK_HOME='C:/Users/Admin/anaconda3/Scripts'`; but when I do that, pyspark stops working (findspark.init() still not working).

If anyone can explain what is going on, I'd be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the full exception message?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add PySpark to the Python3 kernel

`pip install`, like you've said you have done

> there is not much difference in performance

You're only using one machine, so there wouldn't be

> When is PySpark preferred/beneficial over pandas and scikit-learn?

When you want to deploy the same code onto an actual Spark cluster and your dataset is stored in distributed storage

---

You don't necessarily need `findspark` if your environment variables are already setup